# How to Use MP3Loop Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've found a loop class for actionscript. I'm new to classes and I don't know how to use it. I mean I'm getting error

```
Sahne 1, Katman ‘Katman 1’, Kare 1, Satır 3, Sütun 1    1180: Olası tanımlanmamış bir MP3Loop yöntemi çağrısı.
```

Here's my code:

```
import LoopClass;

MP3Loop();
```

And here's the class file which I modified: http://pastebin.com/DUst2nVu

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What?! Please read the FAQ how to ask a question..

Comment: Maybe if you translate the error to English...

Comment: thanks for the answers. translation: Scene 1, Layer 'Katman 1', Frame 1, Line 3, Column 1    Call to a possibly undefined method MP3Loop